# How to change by fadeIN a backgound color using a timer and a slider in java?

Tags: java, swing, timer, colors, slider

I want to change the background of a frame using a slider to set the delay for the timer that when the delay will finish the color of the background will fadeIN.

the fadeIN color should be  on a new  frame , that will  apear when a jButton is pressed.

Any help will be very apreciated !

EDIT:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9eQY.jpg]

I choose color and then select the speed  between 100 - 3000 milisec. When I press start, the color must change with the speed  from the slider.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796871/how-to-slowly-change-object-color-from-one-to-another/29802041#29802041 for an example of fading the background of a component.

Comment: I edit my post hopefully will get more help and be understanded :)