# Event Listener to change the button color when clicked

Tags: java, swing, button, event-listener, eventhandler

How to change the focus listener to only action performed, so when the button clicked, it will trigger the fade method?

[image]

```
class FaderTimer implements FocusListener, ActionListener {
    private ArrayList colors;
    private JButton component;
    private Timer timer;
    private int alpha;
    private int increment;

    FaderTimer(ArrayList colors, JButton component, int interval) {
        this.colors = colors;
        this.component = component;
        component.addFocusListener(this);
        timer = new Timer(interval, this);
    }

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        alpha = 0;
        increment = 1;
        timer.start();
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        alpha = steps;
        increment = -1;
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        alpha += increment;

        component.setBackground((Color) colors.get(alpha));

        if (alpha == steps || alpha == 0) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: You'll need two `ActionListener`s, one for the button and one for the `Timer`

Comment: You also have to take into consideration that the original code is fading in AND out, so you'll need to decide on what actions should be taken (are you fading in OR out)

Comment: i want to fading in when the button is clicked, how's that be? @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ask a question people need to know the context of the question. It looks like you copied the code from an answer like: [How to slowly change object color from one to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796871/how-to-slowly-change-object-color-from-one-to-another/29802041#29802041)

That code was designed to fade the background on focusGained and focusLost events.

So your requirement is to do this on a button click. So basically you need to add an ActionListener to the button to invoke the the logic found in the focusGained(...) event.

One way to do this might be:

```
//component.addFocusListener(this);
component.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        alpha = 0;
        increment = 1;
        timer.start();
    }   
});
```

Comment: yes @camickr , i was copied that code from the link you provided, i am sorry for not including the source link in my question , but thank you for your answer, i'll try it out..

Comment: if i want to make it fade in when textfield is not empty, and fade out when textfield is empty, how to do it @camickr