# how to change color of Background with deltatime

Tags: java, swing, background

How to change color of Background with deltatime?

Array with 2 elements with 2 random colors, need to change color depending on deltatime.

like this:

First tick of deltatime = color2[0];

Second tick of deltatime = color2[1];

third tick = color2[0]

e

t

c

it's work with loop:

```
privite void fillArray() {
  for (int i = 0; i <c2.length ; i++) {
     c2[i] = new Color ((int)(Math.random() * 256f), (int) (Math.random() * 256f), (int) (Math.random() * 256f));
  }
}

void render(GameCanvas gameCanvas, Graphics g) {
  for (int i = 0; i < c2.length; i++) {
     g.setColor(c2[5]);
  }
  g.fillRect(gameCanvas.getX(), gameCanvas.getY(), gameCanvas.getWidth(), gameCanvas.getHeight());
}
```

but i need use deltatime

render: draw Background

```
void render(GameCanvas gameCanvas, Graphics g) {
  g.fillRect(gameCanvas.getX(), gameCanvas.getY(), gameCanvas.getWidth(), gameCanvas.getHeight());
}

void update(GameCanvas gameCanvas, float deltaTime) {
    //  here is should be code to change color. plz help
}
```

Comment: You need to use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to animate the background color changes. Each time the Timer fires you get the next color from the Array and repaint the background. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796871/how-to-slowly-change-object-color-from-one-to-another/29802041#29802041 for a working example that fades in/out the background as a component gains/loses focus.

Comment: Thanks, it's work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to slowly change object color from one to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796871/how-to-slowly-change-object-color-from-one-to-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case looks like this:
But this without deltatime.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class Background extends JPanel {
   Color drawColor = Color.BLACK;
   private final int delay = 150;


   public Background() {
   //   repaint();
      ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Color color = new Color((int) (Math.random() * 256f), (int) (Math.random() * 256f), (int) (Math.random() * 256f));
            drawColor = color;
         }
      };

      Timer t = new Timer(delay, action);
      t.setRepeats(true);
      t.setInitialDelay(0);
      t.start();
   }

   public void render(Graphics g, GameCanvas gameCanvas){
      g.setColor(drawColor);
      g.fillRect(gameCanvas.getX(), gameCanvas.getY(), gameCanvas.getWidth(), gameCanvas.getHeight());
   }
}
```