# Can't write animation for JComponent to smoothly change rectangle'a colors to grey

Tags: java, swing, graphics, timer

I faced the problem that I can't write an animation for color change at the Rectangle of JComponent. I use Java 8 and Swing. This animation is supposed to be slow, for any amount of seconds I would like to set. Nit: It feels like the base which I need to wrote his thing is definetly timer. 
Here is the code snippet which describes my component's state:

```
class PBtn extends JComponent {
private LinkedList<MyBtn> myBtns = new LinkedList<>();

LinkedList<MyBtn> getMyBtns(){
    return myBtns;
}


static class MyBtn extends Rectangle {
    String name;
    Color color;

    MyBtn(int x, int y, int width, int height, String name, Color color) {
        this.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        this.color = color;

    }


}

void addBtn(int x, int y, int width, int height, String name, Color color) {
    MyBtn myBtn = new MyBtn(x, y, width, height, name, color);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            if (myBtn.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                setToolTipText(name);
            }
            ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().mouseMoved(e);
        }
    });
    myBtns.add(myBtn);
    repaint();
}

void clearBtns() {
    myBtns.clear();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    myBtns.forEach(n -> {
        graphics2D.setColor(n.color);
        graphics2D.draw(n);
        graphics2D.fill(n);
    });
}
```

I tried to use the interpolation-based animation library bu it didn't help. Can you please give me suggestions how to write this code from scratch? Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, you should use a swing Timer. Read its javadoc to know how it works. Then start one which, every N milliseconds, changes the color and calls repaint() on your component.

Comment: Maybe this posting will give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796871/how-to-slowly-change-object-color-from-one-to-another/29802041#29802041. It fades the background of a component from one color to another. You provide information like the speed of the animation, the number of steps to transition the color and the final color.